# MAX31888 on ATtiny

Tags: sensor, attiny, atmel-studio, 1-wire

I'm using an ATtiny13A, which I'm trying to read a [MAX31888](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX31888.pdf) temperature sensor with.
I've been given one of said sensors on a breakout board wired according to this diagram:

[image: fig0_wiring_diag_max31888]

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/lpodkalicki/attiny-onewire-library) to try and read the temperature from said sensor. The sensor is wired to the MCU like so:

```
Sensor        |  ATtiny13A
DQ  [Grey]   ->  PB0 (With a 4.7KΩ pullup)
GND [Purple] ->  GND (duh.)
CEXT[Blue]   ->  3.3Vcc
```

I'm doing all of this in Microchip/Atmel studio in a simple Atmel_GCC project for ATtiny13A, with a CPU-frequency of 1.2MHz.

So far, using this OW sequence:

```
RESET, 0XCC, 0X44, (20ms delay), RESET, 0XCC, 0xBE
```

I get either: `0XFF, 0X33` or `0XFF, 0X00` when reading the response bytes from the sensor.

If I use `0X33` instead of `0XBE` during the OW sequence, and read 5-bytes as the datasheet suggests, I get all 5 response bytes as `0X30`.

I'm sure that I'm just doing the sequence wrong, since my test setup works fine with a DS18B20 sensor, and all of the breakout samples I got for the MAX31888 sensor give me the same result.

What would be the correct sequence for getting the temperature buffer from this sensor? Or is there a fundamental difference in how this sensor is supposed to be connected to the circuit?

Comment: @Antonio51 There is. It's on the diagram, minus the capacitor value